# I'd like to book a flight transiting Dublin in order to use hidden-city ticketing. How can I find all flights transiting through Dublin from NYC?

Tags: layovers, dublin, hidden-city-ticketing

I am wanting to find a flight from New York, NY, that has a layover in Dublin. What destination cities would I need to look at in order to obtain a layover in Dublin, Ireland?

Comment: Do you want a *layover* (a connection time of a few hours, during which you may not be allowed to pass immigration to enter Ireland), or a *stopover* (a visit of a full day or more, during which you do enter Ireland)?

Comment: A layover, since Dublin is my "real" destination. The idea being, find an inexpensive one-way flight to a destination with a connection in Dublin, and then just stay in Dublin since that is my destination anyway. Flights into Dublin on 12/26/16 are obviously expensive, and most have connections going through through other cities such as Birmingham or Amsterdam. So, my thought is, why not find a flight to another city, with a connection through Dublin, and just not make the connection? Since I'll be doing it as a one-way, I won't lose a return flight by missing my connection.

Comment: https://skiplagged.com/

Comment: I've updated the question title, I think it now reflects what you want more accurately

Comment: @JonathanReez: I think this is technically [tag:hidden-city-ticketing], not throwaway (which is using only one leg of a round-trip ticket).  Angela: you might want to browse that link to see other possible hazards of this approach.

Answer (score 5):

One way flights from the US are typically quite expensive whatever the destination, because using two oneway tickets together you can defeat restrictions imposed by the cheaper round trip tickets such as minimum stays or Saturday nights. Therefore twice a oneway fare will *usually* be at least as expensive as the cheapest restricted roundtrip ticket, although this is not always true.

In any event, you can use the [ITA Matrix](https://matrix.itasoftware.com) to construct this kind of search.

I give an example of how to do this in the included screenshot.

[image: ITA search]

Click the *Advanced routing codes* link. In the new box that appears between origin and destination, enter the routing syntax `F+ DUB F+`. This means *at least one flight*, then a *transit through Dublin*, then *at least one flight*. For the destination, give a list of European cities. Off the top of my head I gave

```
LON, BHX, AMS, PAR, MAN, EDI, MAD, BCN, ROM, FRA, STO, OSL
```

If you want to narrow that list down, look for places served by Aer Lingus on the [Dublin airport Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Airport#Passenger), as this carrier is competing with nonstops offered by other carriers. Don't make the list of destinations too long as the Matrix will *not* check every possible option. Instead, once your list goes above about ten, split it into several searches.

I assume you are happy to make connections before you get to Dublin, but you can change the routing command if you want direct flights. If you only want direct flights to Dublin, use `N DUB F+`. The `N` means *exactly one non stop flight*.

In order to book the itinerary, go to the website of the carrier in question, or try Expedia, or your favourite travel agent, and search for exactly the flights that ITA suggests.